# Special Distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A personnel manager is interviewing potential employees in order to fill two jobs. The probability of an interviewee having the necessary qualifications and accepting an offer is 80%.
(a) Find the probability that exactly four people must be interviewed
(b) Find the probability that fewer than four people must be interviewed

First, I think the problem is about negative binomial distribution
my approach for a is :

$$
\begin{aligned} P(x=4)&= \binom{x-1}{k-1}*\theta^{k}*(1-\theta )^{x-k} 
\\ &=\binom{4-1}{2-1} * 0.8^{2} * (1-0.8)^{4-2} 
\\ &= 0.0768 \end{aligned}
$$

my problem is b,
$$
\begin{aligned}P(x<3)&=\binom{x-1}{k-1}\theta^{k}(1-\theta )^{x-k}\\&=\binom{3-1}{2-1}0.8^{2}(1-0.8)^{3-2}+\binom{2-1}{2-1}0.8^{2}(1-0.8)^{2-2} \\ &= 0.69128 \end{aligned}
$$

0.69128 does not correspond to the correct solution. I don't know what I am missing here. Could anyone help me out here, please?

Comment: This is hard to read.  As these are independent trials with a binary outcome, the probability of getting exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials is $P(n,k)=\binom nk\times .8^k\times .2^{n-k}$.  For $(a)$ you want $P(4,2)$ and for $(b)$ you want $P(3,2)+P(2,2)$.

Comment: Note that $P(2,2)=.8^2=.64$ which is already *much* larger than your result.

Comment: @lulu, Hmm, are you saying this is not a Negative Binomial Problem? Because your formula is Binomial formula and with it, the output is still not correct, though.

Comment: Ah, there was an error in what I wrote.  It's not $P(3,2)+P(2,2)$ because that double counts the cases in which the first two are successes.  The "good" outcomes are $SS, SFS,FSS$  where $F$ means "Fail" and $S$ means "Success".

Comment: Similarly for the first part, it's not $P(4,2)$ because  you need the last interview to be a Success (since otherwise you'd have stopped prior to that interview).  Thus the good outcomes are $SFFS, FSFS, FFSS$.

Comment: @lulu. Thank you! I just realised that I was confused by different forms of formulas. Now I got it.